# Can PLSS in atmosphere use enriched oxygen?

Tags: spacesuits, oxygen, plss

[Does Mars space suit have to be pressurized?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/715/does-mars-space-suit-have-to-be-pressurized) makes it pretty clear the atmospheric pressure on Mars is a miniscule fraction of Earth's own.

In it's turn [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Mars) writes to say that the atmosphere of Mars is mostly [Carbon Dioxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_Dioxide). This is at odds with Earth orbit (where the space-walks happen). It is also significantly different from the vacuum experienced by the Apollo astronauts on Luna.

The [PLSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_Life_Support_System) together with the [EMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-vehicular_mobility_unit) form a closed system relative to the Martian atmosphere, is there any reason to change the **breathing mixture** in the PLSS for use in atmosphere?

Answer (score 1):

The oxygen mixture depends on the pressure. The pressure limits on a space suit are basically limited to the fact that an inflated space suit tends to become stiff, much as a balloon that is blown up is stiff. The pressure on Mars isn't different enough where there will be a significant pressure difference, thus, if a current generation space suit were used on Mars, the pressure/ oxygen mixture would most likely remain nearly identical.