# Why have JPL martian rovers stopped using airbags and started using skycranes?

Tags: landing, entry-descent-landing, air-bag, skycrane

Pathfinder and the Mars Exploration Rovers used airbags to kill their terminal velocity. The Curiosity and Mars 2020 rovers have or will use skycranes. Why have JPL started using propulsive terminal landings? Surely it's less efficient and more risky than the tried-and-true airbag solution that has been in use since the first Lunas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What problems led to the use of the Sky Crane system used by Curiosity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-problems-led-to-the-use-of-the-sky-crane-system-used-by-curiosity)

Comment: Chantilas' spleen?

Comment: Square-Cube ratio makes cushioning airbags less effective for heavier objects.